# react bootstrap how to convert columns to rows on smaller screens?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hi I'm new to react (and not great with css for that matter) and im trying to create a portfolio website. For desktop screen sizes (16:9) I have two columns but when I zoom in, it continues to stay 2 columns (as expected). Would someone guide me to changing the columns to rows so I have two rows instead of two columns on smaller screens? I suspect maybe im not understanding bootstrap well here.

```
return (
        <div className="App">
            <Container fluid={true} className="god-container" style={{paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0}}>
                <Row className="god-row" style={{marginRight: 0, marginLeft: 0}}>
                    <Col xs="12" md="3" className="sidebar" style={{paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0}}> 
                        <About></About>
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs="12" md="9" className="not-sidebar">
                        <ProjectSection projects={projects}/>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Can you fork one of these https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/react-bootstrap out with your code?

Comment: no problem. Am working on it

Comment: Here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/rdg-column-filtering-forked-q4wv7?file=/src/components/Links/Links.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked your code and the Bootstrap grid is fine. There is an element `about` which is given a fixed positioning and a width of 25% which is forcing it to override the Bootstrap grid and stay in two columns even in small devices. I don't think you will need that code in about but if you need it then you can use the below code to target for smaller devices.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .about {
      width: unset;
      position: unset;
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** https://n1zw2.csb.app/

Comment: thank you so much! I needed it fixed so it would stay in the same position as the user scrolls down the project section. I really need to start learning media queries.

Comment: do you know how I can vertically align all the other items in the project section on mobile screen sizes as well? As you notice, they continue to stay in rows with 3 columns per row. Thanks!

Comment: @bg9848 Can you please open a new question? I can explain it better then.

Comment: ok I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63872524/react-bootstrap-how-to-vertically-align-columns-within-row-for-mobile-screen-siz